# Using drivers not supplied by server motherboard manufacturer

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, best-practices

Is it considered bad practice/risky to use drivers for servers not provided by the motherboard manufacturer? My on board NIC drivers supplied by the manufacturer of my motherboard were released in summer 2012 and Intel has released several newer drivers for this chip.

Comment: Check the NIC for a setting named "Energy Efficient Ethernet". If it has it turn it off and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Are you referring to Power Management settings in the control panel? There is a Power Management Tab in the NIC configuration dialog which has 'Reduce Link Speed to Save Power' checked. I can try that.

Comment: @joeqwerty yea that really sucks ms should just see that hyper-v is installed and turn powersavings off!

Comment: actually the setting I described only goes into effect during standby, and a server can't enter standby when it is configured with Hyper-v Role

Comment: @gravidThoughts - No I'm referring to a setting in the Advanced properties of the NIC. Bring up the connection properties and then click the Configure button for the NIC. Go to the Advanced tab and look for a setting named "Energy Efficient Ethernet". If it exists it's probably enabled by default. Disable it and see if that resolves the problem. I had a very similar issue with Hyper-V VM's under Server 2012 with a GB Intel NIC.

Comment: @joeqwerty no such thing in my advanced tab. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it considered bad practice/risky to use drivers for servers not
>   provided by the motherboard manufacturer?

Not if the ones provided by the motherboard manufacturer aren't stable - feel free to do whatever you need to do.

Certainly we *try* to stick to a known working driver set but these things happen and ultimately if you're happy to support the combination then that's what matter.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to get Drivers from the board manufacturer first, but I am not opposed to getting suitable drivers from the chip manufacturer if there is a reason to not use the board manufacturer drivers.  It doesn't hurt to do a quick google on the driver in question first just to see if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394763(WS.10).aspx there are a few hotfixes that may resolve some of your issues.

Comment: unfortunately i have applied the hot fixes for this issue and it is still a problem.